# Python 3 print utf-8 encoded string problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm requesting a string from a network-service. When I print it from within a program:

```
variable = getFromNetwork()
print(variable)
```

and I execute it using `python3 net.py` I get:

```
\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612
```

When I execute in the python3 CLI:

```
>>> print("\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612")
ØªÙ
Ù
Ù612
```

Buy when I execute in the python2 CLI I get the correct result:

```
>>> print("\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612")
تملي612
```

How I can print this in my program by python3?

### Edit

After executing the following line:

```
print(print(type(variable), repr(variable)))
```

Got

```
<class 'str'> '\\xd8\\xaa\\xd9\\x85\\xd9\\x84\\xd9\\x8a612'
```

I think I should first remove`\\x` to make it hex and then decode it. What is your solutions!?

Comment: `print(b"\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612".decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: How can i put that `b` before variable name??? @MauriceMeyer

Comment: Does ``print(variable)`` actually produce ``\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612``, ``"\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612"``, or ``b"\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612"``?

Comment: It is just `\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612` @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Please provide the output of ``print(type(variable), repr(variable))``.

Comment: Added @MisterMiyagi

Comment: FWIW, while we can help "fix" the issue (see the answer by Serge Ballesta) the actual issue is that ``getFromNetwork`` is broken. It should *either* provide an undecoded bytes, or a properly decoded string. Currently, it provides and incorrectly decoded string.

Comment: Yes the problem is from network. Serge's answer is not working too! @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the encoding, so the interpreter knows how to interpret the data:

```
s = "\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612"
y = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
print (y)  # is a bytes object now!
print (y.decode('utf-8'))
```

Out:

```
b'\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612'
تملي612
```

Comment: I tried your solution, And got `b'\\xd8\\xaa\\xd9\\x85\\xd9\\x84\\xd9\\x8a612'` and
`\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612` for result!

Comment: @Fastask: This works on 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, which version are you using ?

Comment: Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)

Comment: Please debug `variable` correctly as mentioned by MisterMiyagi.

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Fix whatever creates 'stockInfo', there shouldn't be double backslashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218198/discussion-between-fastask-and-maurice-meyer).

Comment: @Fastask: Please open up a new question and additionally describe what `getFromNetwork` is doing. The information provided here is not sufficient to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is a (unicode) string that contains code for a UTF8 encoded byte string. It can happen because it was erroneously decoded with a wrong encoding (probably Latin1 here).

You can fix it by first converting to a byte string without changing the codes (so with a Latin1 encoding) and then you will be able to correctly decode it:

```
variable = getFromNetwork().encode('Latin1').decode()
print(variable)
```

Demo:

```
variable = "\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612"
print(variable.encode('Latin1').decode())

تملي612
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 3 i tested with the following code

```
    line='\xd8\xaa\xd9\x85\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a612'
    line = line.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
    line=line.decode("utf-8")
    print(line)
```

it prints

```
تملي612
```

Comment: `b` is a python3 syntax to create a byte-string. You don't need declare a variable beforehand that it will hold a byte-string. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62992137/edit) and add to your question what you are trying to do. Or open a new question.